# Restrict Javascript modification of particular objects' hrefs / find out WHAT is modifying the hrefs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working with a really old application that fills a `div` by calling a JavaScript on a remote server and injecting the content into the DOM.

For some reason, in Firefox, it is also replacing all of my URL hosts with another host address.

This behavior is not happening in Chrome or IE.

While I would to prevent this from happening by fixing the application, I more immediately need to know if I can write some JavaScript to "protect" particular elements in the document from being modified. (ie, the `href` attribute of several objects)

Is this even possible?

Even better, is there some way I can use the developer tools to find out exactly *what* line of the script is causing my links' domain to change?

Comment: Try [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Object.defineProperty() to make the property readonly.

```
 Object.defineProperty(obj, "key", {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: "static"
 });
```

**Source:**

[defineProperty MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

**Note:**

**defineProperty** is not supported in old browsers, if you want to support old browsers, you have to use closures to protect the data from outside. You will provide them getters, so that others can access your read only data.